# Example of the inequality $c_0\neq\bigcup l_p$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

As part of an exercise, I was asked to prove or disprove the following proposition:

There exists an $x\in c_o$, such that $x\notin l_p$ for every $1\le p\lt\infty$.

Before I show my proof, I will state my questions:
1) Is the following proof correct?
2) Is there a simpler proof?
3) What would be an example of such an $x$?

**Proof:** Since $l_p\subseteq c_0$ for every $1\le p\lt\infty$ (the convergence of $\sum_{n}|\xi_n|^p$ implies $\xi_n\rightarrow 0$) the above proposition is equivalent to $c_0\subsetneq\bigcup{l_p}$. To prove this I used Baire's Category theorem as follows:

Assume that $c_0=\bigcup{l_p}$. We show that $l_p$ (for $p\lt\infty$) is a closed subspace of $c_0$.
First, closure under addition and scalar multiplication is immediate, since these are defined identically in $l_p$ and in $c_0$. This shows that $l_p$ is indeed a subspace.
Next, we show that $\|x_n-x\|_p\rightarrow 0$ implies $\|x_n-x\|_\infty\rightarrow 0$, where $x_n=(\xi_k^{(n)}),\,x=(\xi_k)\in l_p$.
For every $k, n$ we have:
$$
|\xi_k^{(n)} -\xi_k|^p\le\sum_{m}|\xi_m^{(n)} -\xi_m|^p
$$
Therefore, for every $n$:
$$
\|x_n-x\|_\infty=\sup_k|\xi_k^{(n)} -\xi_k|\le\left(\sum_{m}|\xi_m^{(n)} -\xi_m|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}=\|x_n-x\|_p
$$
This shows that the subspace $l_p$ is closed in $c_0$.
Using this result, along with the fact that $c_0$ is a complete space, we can apply Baire's theorem to our assumption ($c_0=\bigcup{l_p}$), and conclude that there is some $1\le p\lt\infty$, for which there are $x_0=(\xi_n)\in l_p$ and $r>0$ such that for every $x\in c_0$, the inequality $\|x_0-x\|_\infty\lt r$ implies $x\in l_p$.
Let $N$ be such that $\xi_n<\frac{r}{4}$ whenever $n > N$. We define $x_1=(\eta_n)\in c_0$ as follows:
$$
\eta_n := \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    \xi_n \,,&  n \le \max\{N,\, \left(\frac{4}{r}\right)^p\} \\
    \sqrt[p]{\frac{1}{n}} \,,& \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}
\right.
$$
Thus, we have $\|x_0-x_1\|_\infty\lt r$, but $x_1\notin l_p$ - a contradiction.

Comment: What is $c_0$? Sequences converging to zero? If that is the case, just try $x_n = \frac{1}{\log n}$.

Comment: Funny, I could'nt think of this simple example, but I could think of an overly elaborate proof.